# How to programmatically close a MessageDialog in Win8 app using WinJS?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698666/how-to-close-message-dialog-programmatically) to mine regarding how to programmatically close a MessageDialog in a Win8 app, but the author of the question is using C#.  I'm curious about how to solve the issue with WinJS.  Is there any way to cancel a MessageDialog programmatically with WinJS without have access to the CommanUI objects within the dialog itself?  I cannot simply invoke  the handler associated with an appended CommandUI button since, in some cases, I wouldn't know which button index has that functionality.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`MessageDialog.showAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.showasync.aspx) returns an [`IAsyncOperation<IUICommand>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx) object and inherits from [`IAsyncInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.aspx).  The [`IAsyncInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.aspx) interface includes a [`cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.cancel.aspx) method which generically cancels asynchronous operations.  In the case of the message dialog, calling cancel on the  async operation will dismiss the dialog if it is still present.

```
var asyncOperation = messageDialog.showAsync();
asyncOperation.cancel();
```

More info on the [WinRT asynchronous programming pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464924.aspx) can be found on MSDN.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This is absolutely unclear from the documentation, but works perfectly.