# Closing MessageDialog programatically in WP 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to close and hide the `MessageDialog` in Windows Phone 8.1 RT. I've seen multiple solutions from calling `.Cancel()` and `.Close()`, but none work on Windows Phone 8.1 RT; they're valid only for Windows 8 RT.

How can I close the `MessageDialog` from code without interacting with it?

Comment: You should try this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698666/how-to-close-message-dialog-programmatically

Comment: Tried that; it only works on Windows and not Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ContentDialog` instead `MessageDialog`. ContentDialog has more customization options. You can create ContentDialog which looks like MessageDialog without any problems, and hide it from code.

Sample:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ShowContentDialog("cos");
    await HideContentDialog();
}

ContentDialog _contentDialog;
private void ShowContentDialog(string s)
{
        _contentDialog = new ContentDialog();
    _contentDialog.Content = s;
    _contentDialog.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true;
    _contentDialog.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";
    _contentDialog.Title = "title";
    _contentDialog.ShowAsync();
}

private async Task HideContentDialog()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    _contentDialog.Hide();
}
```

Comment: This is useful for UWP apps as well.